# Fazendo soma com angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Alguem poderia me ajudar, estou começando a usar Angular agora, e estou tendo uma grande confusão na hora de como estudar...

Basicamente, quando eu clico no botão ele não faz nada...
é possivel que o erro seja grotesco, mas estou travado

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Valor 1"
(input) = 'valor1'

 />
<input type="text" placeholder="Valor 2"
(input) = 'valor2'

 />
<button (click)="calcularSoma(valor1, valor2)" class="btn btn-primary">Calcular</button>
<p>
  {{calcularSoma(valor1, valor2)}}
</p>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calculator',
  templateUrl: './calculator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calculator.component.css']
})
export class CalculatorComponent  {

  value1: number;
  value2: number;
  constructor() {

   }

   calcularSoma(value1:  number,  value2: number){
     return this.value1 + this.value2;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legal que esteja aprendendo, então, tem muitos erros de sintaxe tanto no seu código **HTML** como no seu **TS**. Para você pegar um valor de um input uma maneira muito utilizada *(mas não é a única)* é com a diretiva **ngModel**, esta diretiva faz o chamado **Two way data binding**, ou seja, basicamente ela transmite o valor do HTML para o TS e vice-versa. Bom como já pegamos o valor do input, agora é só somar na função **calcularSoma** e guardar o valor em uma variável total e mostrar na tela, pois também não é muito recomendado executar funções diretamente no HTML:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {  
  value1;
  value2;
  valorTotal;

  constructor() {}

  calcularSoma(){
     this.valorTotal = Number(this.value1) + Number(this.value2);
  }

}
```

---

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Valor 1" [(ngModel)]="value1">
<input type="text" placeholder="Valor 2" [(ngModel)]="value2">

<button (click)="calcularSoma()" class="btn btn-primary">Calcular</button>
<p>
  {{ valorTotal }} <br>
</p>
```

> O método **Number()** foi utilizado pois o valor de um input vai ser sempre **string** se o type for text, mesmo tipando a variável como number, o que concatenaria os valores ao invés de soma-los.

Comment: Obrigado! Foi de extrema, não estou nem um pouco acostuma com essas 2 linguagens operando dessa forma... Se nao for incomodar, poderia me tirar uma duvida? O porque do Property Binding ou Event Binding não estava funcionando?

Comment: O **Event Binding** não estava funcionando pq basicamente vc não estava pegando o valor digitado no input. Para funcionar teria que fazer algo como **(input)="valor1 = $event.target.value"**.